# Preparing Python Virtual Environment for Flink

Tags: python-venv, pyflink

I cannot find the `setup-pyflink-virtual-env.sh` mentioned here [Preparing Python Virtual Environment](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/python/faq/#preparing-python-virtual-environment). The link does not work in the article. The lastest version found is for flink 1.12 [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/downloads/setup-pyflink-virtual-env.sh). Is there a newer version and where can I find it?